# how to increment value while clicking button click in MVC (ajax call not form submit)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I tried to increase count when clicking button (ajax call) in MVC, but value is incremented one time only. actually i have update the model after increment but it is not keeping updated model. please suggest how to solve?

My ultimate aim is:
what i want is on ajax call i want to pass model to actionmethod and do some set value to model and send back. while next button click i have to send updated model. thats all.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Integer { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
}

public class Test1Controller : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var m = new MyModel();
        return View("Test1", m);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangeTheValue(MyModel model)
    {
        model.Integer++;
        UpdateModel(model);
        return Json(model.Integer.ToString());

    }

}
enter code here
@model MvcApplication2.Model.MyModel

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test1";
  }
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>

   <h2>Test1</h2>
   @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1"         }))
   {
      <div>
       <input type="button" onclick="ajaxcall()" id="changeButton" value="Click Me!" />
       <input type="text" value="@Model.Integer" class="txt" id="str" name="str" />

     </div>
     }
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function ajaxcall() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("ChangeTheValue", "Test1")',
            data: $('form1').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                 $("#str").val(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                 alert("Err " + data);
            }

          });
         }


        </script>
```

[image]

Comment: One thing to mention is that your $('form1') selector will not select anything, which is probably why it is failing. Your form has the id="form1", meaning that you need to use the id selector (#). $("#form1").serialize() to get the form data to pass through on the ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending data via str's value instead of the whole form:

```
function ajaxcall() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("ChangeTheValue", "Test1")',
           data: $('#str').val(),
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                 $("#str").val(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                 alert("Err " + data);
            }

          });
```

Comment: This inadvertently solves the problem, although the .val needs parentheses as it is a getter function, not a property. The correct selector would be $("#str").val() for the data attribute on the ajax call

Comment: @mhodges : right, fixed that. Also, your ajax post method would be better of with accepting an `int` instead of the model if you go this way: `public ActionResult ChangeTheValue(int str)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all your jQuery selecctor for the form is wrong! Since `form1` is the id, you should prefix it with `#`

```
data: $('#form1').serialize(),
```

And in your Action method, you are updating the value of the property `Integer`. But you are setting it the field with name `str` after the ajax call. So next time, when you click again, it is going to read the default value of `Integar` property ( which is 0 and increase it once to 1) and return you again. (This happens for all the clicks since you are not sending the updated value of that property).So ideally you should fix your form to have the correct field names

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="ajaxcall()" id="changeButton" value="Click Me!" />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.Str)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.Integer)

    </div>
}
```

And in the success event you should be updating the form field for `Integer` property.

```
success: function (data) {
   $("#Integer").val(data);
},
```

Comment: Thanks every one. what i want is on ajax call i want to pass model to actionmethod and do some set value to model and send back. while next button click i have to send updated model. thats all.